# Processing 3.0: Accelerating pong ball not correctly bouncing

Tags: processing, bounce, pong

I'm learning Processing and am making modified version of pong game in processing 3. I have 2 balls simultaneously instead of just 1.
Also, one ball accelerates while the other ball slows down as the program runs.

My accelerating ball is working fine, it bounces around and increases speed. But, my slowing down ball is not working correct. The slowing ball moves in a very small area and does not even go close to the borders to bounce off. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.`

```
float ballXPosition;
float ballYPosition;
float ballTwoXPos;
float ballTwoYPos;
float xDirection;
float ballTwoXDir;
float yDirection;
float ballTwoYDir;
float radius = 12;
float xSpeed;
float ySpeed;
float ballTwoXSpeed;
float ballTwoYSpeed;
float MAX_SPEED = 15;
float MIN_SPEED = 0.2;

void setup()
{
  size(600,600);
  stroke(3);
  background(255,255,255);

  ballXPosition = width/2 + random(60);
  ballTwoXPos= width/2 + random(60); 

  ballYPosition = height/2 + random(60);
  ballTwoYPos = height/2 + random(60);

  xDirection = random(1,3);
  ballTwoXDir = random(1,3);

  yDirection = random(1,3);
  ballTwoYDir = random(1,3);

  xSpeed = MIN_SPEED;
  ySpeed = MIN_SPEED;

  ballTwoXSpeed = MAX_SPEED;
  ballTwoYSpeed = MAX_SPEED;
}

void createAcceleratingBall(float xpos, float ypos, float xstretch, float ystretch)
{
  fill(255,0,0);
  ellipse(xpos, ypos, xstretch, ystretch);
}

void createSlowingBall(float xpos, float ypos, float xstretch, float ystretch)
{
  fill(0,0,255);
  ellipse(xpos, ypos, xstretch, ystretch);
}

boolean isSpeedMax(float speed)
{
  return speed > MAX_SPEED;
}

boolean isSpeedMin(float speed)
{
  return speed < MIN_SPEED;
}

boolean isBallAtXBorder(float xpos)
{
  if(xpos < radius || xpos > width - radius)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

boolean isBallAtYBorder(float ypos)
{
  if(ypos < radius || ypos > height - radius)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);

  ballXPosition = ballXPosition + (xDirection * xSpeed);
  ballTwoXPos = ballTwoXPos + (ballTwoXDir * ballTwoXSpeed);

  ballYPosition = ballYPosition + (yDirection * ySpeed);
  ballTwoYPos = ballTwoYPos + (ballTwoYDir * ballTwoYSpeed);

  if(!isSpeedMax(xSpeed))
    xSpeed *= 1.005;

  if(!isSpeedMax(ySpeed))
    ySpeed *= 1.003;

  if(!isSpeedMin(ballTwoXSpeed))
    ballTwoXSpeed = ballTwoXSpeed / 1.005;

  if(!isSpeedMin(ballTwoYSpeed))
    ballTwoYSpeed = ballTwoYSpeed / 1.003;

  if(isBallAtXBorder(ballXPosition))
    xDirection *= -1;

  if(isBallAtYBorder(ballYPosition))
    yDirection *= -1;

  if(isBallAtXBorder(ballTwoXDir))
    ballTwoXDir *= -1;

  if(isBallAtYBorder(ballTwoYDir))
    ballTwoYDir *= -1;

  createAcceleratingBall(ballXPosition, ballYPosition, 2*radius, 2*radius);
  createSlowingBall(ballTwoXPos, ballTwoYPos, 2.5*radius, 2.5*radius);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong variables being tested for the slowing ball in the `isBallAtXBorder` and `isBallAtYBorder` functions. You're testing `ballTwoXDir` and `ballTwoYDir` - should you not be testing `ballTwoXPos` and `ballTwoYPos`?